# How to implement column or table attributes in Entity of a Domain Driven approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

Entity is an object that is not defined by its attributes, but rather by a thread of continuity and its identity.

I have designed a sipmle entity as following.

```
public class Employee: Entity<Guid>
{
    private string name;

    public string Name { 
       get { return name; } 
       set {
           if(string.IsNollOrEmpty(value))
              throw new Exception("name is required.");
           name = value;
       }
    }
    
    public Employee(string name)
    {           
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

But When I use Entity Framework ORM tool, Column or Table attributes are needed by some stuations.

For example Postgresql database lower case column names.

```
[Table("employees")]
public class Employee: Entity<Guid>
{
   ....
   [Column("name")]
   public string Name {...}
}
```

Oracle needs upper case names.

```
[Table("EMPLOYEES")]
public class Employee: Entity<Guid>
{
   ....
   [Column("NAME")]
   public string Name {...}
}
```

Mssql accepts both name styles.

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee: Entity<Guid>
{
   ....
   [Column("Name")]
   public string Name {...}
}
```

So I could not create 3 different entities. But I need a practical solution. I need only one entity but if database change, my code should not be change.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DDD. Configure the database mapping via fluent API rather than data annotations (attributes). Fluent configuration (`OnModelCreating`)  is separate for each database type, so there you could apply different naming rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

you already gave the answer yourself: "I need only one entity but if database change, my code should not be change."

choose your approach and frameworks according to that guideline. infrastructure concerns should be separated from domain concerns. it is tempting to just annotate domain objects with persistence metadata and be done with it. It will haunt you at some point, because you are not easily able to refactor or evolve your domain objects "towards greater insight" because of tight coupling to the underlying database.

It's a tradeoff like everything. If you are using DDD you should consider favouring untampered/pure domain objects